# Flutter Web Development using an Online IDE

Tags: flutter, dart, single-page-application, cloud9, codio

I am doing my development using a Chromebook and wondered if it is possible to develop SPAs using Flutter using an online IDE such as Cloud9 or Codio?

I have managed to install flutter and run it to install dart but am getting stuck as it can't find a Chrome installation.

Is it possible to develop using the cloud IDE and use by local install of Chrome for testing?

Comment: have your tried to follow the official docs? https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/chromeos

Comment: The official docs require it to be installed as a Linux app in Chrome. Since me work device is locked down and we are encouraged to use cloud IDEs I was hoping this would be supported.

Comment: AFAIK, Github Codespaces will be the only alternative but I think they still are on a closed beta: https://github.com/features/codespaces

Comment: Mariano, can you add this as a solution, I can then mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only closer web approaches are:

- DartPad
- CodePen
- Codespaces

Codespaces being a full VS Code which is currently on Beta Access which will allow the same coding possibilities as the desktop one.

Link: https://github.com/features/codespaces

Answer (score 2):

You can also check flutlab.io. It's working on Chromebook (Flutter IDE and even Figma integration). Proof: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ0ATecs7Fo

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (to CodeSpaces, at least); [GitPod](https://www.gitpod.io/) has a pretty serviceable free tier to build a testing workspace. They actually have a Github template you can fork, then create a workspace from:

https://www.gitpod.io/docs/quickstart/flutter

Another nicety is the stack is [open source](https://www.gitpod.io/blog/opensource) as of last year.